# RowUpdating not firing in EditItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edititemtemplate

I'm binding an array to GridView. Below is my template field and it doesn't fire RowUpdating when I click on update.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' ID="txtEditRole"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

This happened after making the field to TempleteField. Earlier the field was like below.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="!" HeaderText="Role" />
```

Comment: Have you use `OnRowUpdating` event in gridview http://www.webblogsforyou.com/gridview-inline-add-insert-edit-update-delete-data-in-asp-net-c-vb/ like this?

Comment: Yes, I have OnRowUpdating event

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify `OnRowUpdating="gv_RowUpdating"` event and also change *FieldName* in `<%#Eval("Role") %>`, see this example:

**.aspx page**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="gv_RowEditing"      
OnRowUpdating="gv_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gv_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="gv_RowDeleting">
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
     <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
     </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" CausesValidation="false" />
     </ItemTemplate>    
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">
     <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditRole" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Role") %>' />
     </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Role") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>    
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   //your code here..
}
```

To check complete article, checkout [insert, update, delete gridview data example in asp.net](http://www.aspneto.com/gridview-inline-add-insert-edit-update-delete-data-in-asp-net-c-vb.html).

Comment: This doesn't work because I set the data source like follows. gridViewRoles.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles();  So it gives an error 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Role'.

Comment: That's because the "Role" field is not found from the resultset returned by "Roles.GetAllRoles();". Make sure "Role" field is returned within resultset and pass it as a List.